# How can I speed up an iterative function on my large pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I am quite new to pandas and I have a pandas dataframe of about 500,000 rows filled with numbers. I am using python 2.x and am currently defining and calling the method shown below on it. It sets a predicted value to be equal to the corresponding value in series 'B', if two adjacent values in series 'A' are the same. However, it is running extremely slowly, about 5 rows are outputted per second and I want to find a way accomplish the same result more quickly.

```
def myModel(df):

    A_series = df['A']
    B_series = df['B']
    seriesLength = A_series.size

    # Make a new empty column in the dataframe to hold the predicted values
    df['predicted_series'] = np.nan

    # Make a new empty column to store whether or not
    # prediction matches predicted matches B
    df['wrong_prediction'] = np.nan
    prev_B = B_series[0]
    for x in range(1, seriesLength):

        prev_A = A_series[x-1]  
        prev_B = B_series[x-1]
        #set the predicted value to equal B if A has two equal values in a row
        if A_series[x] == prev_A:
            if df['predicted_series'][x] > 0:
                 df['predicted_series'][x] = df[predicted_series'][x-1]
            else:
                 df['predicted_series'][x] = B_series[x-1]
```

Is there a way to vectorize this or to just make it run faster? Under the current circumstances, it is projected to take many hours. Should it really be taking this long? It doesn't seem like 500,000 rows should be giving my program that much problem.

Comment: Are you using Python 3.x? If not, try at least switching from `range` to `xrange`.

Comment: I am using python 2.x. I'll edit my question to include that.

Comment: is this text or numerical data?

Comment: It's all numerical data

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work as you described:

```
df['predicted_series'] = np.where(A_series.shift() == A_series, B_series, df['predicted_series'])
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know if there is a way to add a conditional to the value predicted_series takes? Also, does this run much faster?

Comment: Much faster than loop? Most probably. Much faster than Grr's answer? I'm not sure. For 100 random rows it's 3 times faster than .loc but you should try that out on a larger dataframe. You can give a condition for the predicted series as well. What exactly is the condition?

Comment: Thanks. I will try out both. The condition is that predicted_series is only set to a value when A and previous A are equal. If the previous predicted_series is NaN, then predicted_series equals df.B. Otherwise if previous predicted_series is some number > 0, then predicted_series = previous predicted_series

Comment: We are talking about a dynamic assignment right? When A[n] equals A[n-1], it is filled with B[n], that's OK. If A[n+1]==A[n] too, since pred[n] is not nan, you want pred[n+1] = pred[n], not B[n], am I correct?

Comment: Sorry I don't know any solution to that without using loops. It seems like there is no limit on the number of subsequent A[n]s that can be the same (i.e. 10 in a row can be same as well) so you cannot check with only one shift. You may have a better chance of getting an answer if you ask a new question with that additional constraint.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[df.A.diff() == 0, 'predicted_series'] = df.B
```

This will get rid of the for loop and set predicted_series to the value of B when A is equal to previous A.

**edit:**

per your comment, change your initialization of predicted_series to be all NAN and then front fill the values:

```
df['predicted_series'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.A.diff() == 0, 'predicted_series'] = df.B
df.predicted_series = df.predicted_series.fillna(method='ffill')
```

For fastest speed modifying ayhans answer a bit will perform best:

```
df['predicted_series'] = np.where(df.A.shift() == df.A, df.B, df['predicted_series'].shift())
```

That will give you your forward filled values and run faster than my original recommendation

Comment: Thanks so much! However, is there also a conditional to the value the predicted series takes? Because there are certain conditions where I want the predicted to equal the previous predicted and only 'B' if the previous predicted value is nan, since there are many missing values.

Comment: So let me know if i have this right. You want the value of predicted_series to equal df.B when A and previous A are equal, otherwise you want the value of predicted_series to equal the previous predicted_series value?

Comment: Not exactly, predicted_series is only set to a value when A and previous A are equal. If the previous predicted_series is NaN, then predicted_series equals df.B. Otherwise if previous predicted_series is some number > 0, then predicted_series = previous predicted_series.

Comment: @Richard  I think ayhan's method is actually faster.

Comment: thank you, I am currently testing it out. It is still running. However, just for a slightly deeper understanding, would you mind explaining how you can infer which method is faster?

Comment: @Richard Of course! I am using an Ipython notebook to test the code. If you don't have it, its available in a lot of different environments but I am using the version that comes standard with the [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) distribution of python, called Jupyter Notebook. There you can break your code into blocks which you can execute independently of eachother. More importantly there are a number of "Magic" functions. One of these is `%timeit`. I simply type `%timeit` in front of a line of code and it will give me the average time results of running that loop many times.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```
df.loc[df.A == df.A.shift()] = df.B.shift()
```